# Is there a way to temporarily reserve a Windows 7 PC for a specific user?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-domain

In our lab we have a couple of our more powerful machines, setup for remote access only. User who are members of the lab domain can log on to any of the lab machines, including the ones I just mentioned, using a single pair of `(username,password)`.

We have configured the machines such that all the members of the domain can access it remotely. This step is implemented through `System Properties>>Remote>>Select Users>>Add>><entire domain>`. I am currently implementing a script in Python through which I want to assign the users specific time slots on the machines — hence the question.

Both machines have `Windows 7` installed on them. Had Linux been the operating system, I would imagine there would be some `.config` file which could be edited by the script according to the time slots. What are the options I have on `Windows 7` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

unable to provide script now but will let you know how to achieve this manually,

consider you have **administrator account and standard user account** (Will jr).

Make sure your standard user account do not know your Administrator password, as it would allow them to change or disable Parental Controls for any user account.

**Now set up your parental control from administrator account**

- Go to the Control Panel from the Start Menu.
- Click Set up parental controls for any user.

[image]

- Click on any Standard Account.
  [image]
- Click On to turn Parental Controls on.

[image]
 - Now you can click Time limits to set the time for standard account
   access

**Time limits**

The time limits settings allow you to control when your user can use the computer. Click and drag from any box to allow or block a section of time. If you want, you can set different time limits on different days. For example, you may want to allow more computer use on weekends.

[image]

Hope this helps!